# Передача значения NULL во встроенные функции PHP 8.1

Tags: php

PHP 8.1 на сервере.

Получаю строковое значение из таблицы БД (mariaDB):

```
$db_result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM table1');
$db_result = $db_result->fetch_assoc();
$field1 = trim($db_result['field1']);
```

Все хорошо, но если запрашиваемое значение из БД равно NULL, то получаю следующее предупреждение:

```
PHP Deprecated:  trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in ...
```

Вытаскивая значение из БД я ожидаю получить строку символов, либо пустую строку (в случае NULL) как в предыдущих версиях PHP.

Где-то вычитал, что в последних версиях передавать встроенным функциям значение NULL запрещается.

Примечательно, что следующий код, никаких предупреждений не выдает:

```
echo trim(NULL);
```

Вопрос у меня такой: что предпринять, для того, чтобы NULL из БД интерпретировался как пустая строка? Переписать весь код проекта, добавив дополнительное сравнение на NULL? Может быть в конфиге php можно задать интерпретацию NULL по умолчанию? как?

Answer (score 0):

либо применять пхпшный null coalesce

```
trim($db_result['field1'] ?? 'DEFAULT_VALUE')
```

либо Бдшный. Например в постгрес есть **[COALESCE](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/functions-conditional#functions-coalesce-nvl-ifnull)**

Comment: Т.е.  во всем проекте каждый вызов встроенных функций переписать null coalesce-ом?

Comment: А в случае с БД как применить COALESCE, если в запросе выбирается не только одно поле? для всех полей прописывать?

Comment: "Т.е. во всем проекте каждый вызов встроенных функций переписать null coalesce-ом? " --- вообще не вижу смысла хранить данные в виде NULL, если данные должны быть по-умолчанию строкой..... задать DEFAULT значением пустую строку. Тогда не придётся что-то как-то изголяться

Answer (score 0):

Забавно `<? print trim(NULL);` , пых-пых всё правильно решил.

- https://onlinephp.io/

`Deprecated: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 1`

Исправление:

`trim($db_result['field1'] ?? '')`

Стоит всё же учитывать что PHP переживает сейчас 4ю фазу, где строгая типизация доминирует над ленивым кодом (LazyCode).